# why i can not delete each one and see the result when run out of width of screen?

Tags: java, android, calculator

I try to use some code to delete each one of string and show result when run out of screen but it still can not see. example `1234` when i click it clear all. i want to delete each one.
when insert more number example: `1234556` run out of width of screen. it show `12345` follow the width of screen.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, zero, add,
            sub, mul, div, equal, decimal, cancel, sin, cos, tan, open_bracket, close_bracket,del,log,fac,sqrt,e,pi,mod;
    EditText disp;
    boolean stateError;
    boolean lastNumeric;
    boolean lastDot;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
        two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
        three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);
        four = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
        five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
        six = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);
        seven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
        eight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
        nine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine);
        zero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.zero);

        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sub);
        mul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mul);
        div = (Button) findViewById(R.id.div);
        equal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.equal);
        decimal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.decimal);

        sin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sin);
        cos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cos);
        tan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tan);
        open_bracket = (Button) findViewById(R.id.open_bracket);
        close_bracket = (Button)findViewById(R.id.close_bracket);

        disp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtScreen);
        cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        del = (Button) findViewById(R.id.del);


        try {
            one.setOnClickListener(this);
            two.setOnClickListener(this);
            three.setOnClickListener(this);
            four.setOnClickListener(this);
            five.setOnClickListener(this);
            six.setOnClickListener(this);
            seven.setOnClickListener(this);
            eight.setOnClickListener(this);
            nine.setOnClickListener(this);
            zero.setOnClickListener(this);

            add.setOnClickListener(this);
            sub.setOnClickListener(this);
            mul.setOnClickListener(this);
            div.setOnClickListener(this);
            equal.setOnClickListener(this);
            decimal.setOnClickListener(this);
            cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
            del.setOnClickListener(this);
            sin.setOnClickListener(this);
            cos.setOnClickListener(this);
            tan.setOnClickListener(this);
            open_bracket.setOnClickListener(this);
            close_bracket.setOnClickListener(this);
            log.setOnClickListener(this);
            sqrt.setOnClickListener(this);
            e.setOnClickListener(this);
            pi.setOnClickListener(this);
            fac.setOnClickListener(this);
            mod.setOnClickListener(this);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }


    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Editable str = disp.getText();

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.zero:
                str = str.append(zero.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.one:
                str = str.append(one.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.two:
                str = str.append(two.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.three:
                str = str.append(three.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.four:
                str = str.append(four.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.five:
                str = str.append(five.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.six:
                str = str.append(six.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.seven:
                str = str.append(seven.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.eight:
                str = str.append(eight.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.nine:
                str = str.append(nine.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.add:
                str = str.append(add.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.sub:
                str = str.append(sub.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.mul:
                str = str.append(mul.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.div:
                str = str.append(div.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.decimal:
                str = str.append(decimal.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.sin:
                str = str.append(sin.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.cos:
                str = str.append(cos.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.tan:
                str = str.append(tan.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.buttonSqr:
                str = str.append(String.valueOf(Math.E));
                disp.setText(str);
            case R.id.open_bracket:
                str = str.append(open_bracket.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.close_bracket:
                str = str.append(close_bracket.getText());
                disp.setText(str);
                break;
            case R.id.del:
                if (disp.getText().toString().length() > 1) {
                    String screen_new = disp.getText().toString().substring(0, disp.getText().toString().length() - 1);
                    disp.setText(screen_new);
                } else {
                    disp.setText("");
                }
                lastNumeric = false;
                stateError = false;
                lastDot = false;
            case R.id.cancel:
                disp.setText("");
                break;
            case R.id.equal:
                String val;
                val = disp.getText().toString();
                Expression result ;
                val = val.replaceAll("x", "*").replaceAll("÷", "/").replaceAll("mod","%").replaceAll("e","Math.E")
                        .replaceAll("pi",String.valueOf(Math.PI));
                try {
                     result = new ExpressionBuilder(val).build();
                    disp.setText(Double.toString(result.evaluate()));
            /* size_num = result.calculate(); */
                }catch (ArithmeticException ex) {
                    // Display an error message
                    disp.setText("Error");
                    stateError = true;
                    lastNumeric = false;

                }

                break;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: At a quick glance, I would guess it has to do with `lastNumeric` in your conditional statement. But you should define "doesn't work" when posting. Such as does absolutely nothing, crashes, gives undesired output, etc...

Comment: do you get "Error" message on screen when you do sin(30)?

Comment: can you give me an example?i try to search lots but no solution..

Comment: it doesn't show anything

Comment: use breakpoints to debug this issue. maybe you can find exact location of error.

Comment: when i click 30sin(30) it show and can calculate

Comment: Also, just as an FYI, the library that you are using gives output in radians, not degrees.

Comment: put a breakpoint or log here `if (lastNumeric && !stateError) {` then see what the values are and think about the logic in that statement. I think something will click then.

Comment: so how can i solve this?

Comment: if (lastNumeric && !stateError) { is causing the issue. Just remove it and try

Comment: The exp4j library is very powerful. It can automatically detect if the last element is a numeric or not and it will throw an exception. You do not have to explicitly search for the last element. I know because I have worked with this library extensively in the past.

Comment: i try to do what you said

Comment: okay and then what happened?

Comment: it still the same to before.

Comment: what does txtScreen.getText().toString(); give you in debug mode

Comment: You really need to go through [the Android docs on debugging](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html) and maybe look at some other resources. I'm not trying to be mean but if you can't do these to figure out a simple problem then you are going to hate programming.

Comment: yea @codeMagic that is what I suggest too.

Comment: here the picture of my logcat  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZypWV.png

Comment: can you tell me what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

As @codeMagic says it's probably `lastNumeric` that's giving you the problem.  You are not explicity initializing `lastNumeric` or `stateError` which means they are being initialized to false by default.  In your condition `if (lastNumeric && !stateError)`, if you press the operation first, it will never be executed since `lastNumeric` is false until you press a numeric key.

You can get around this by initializing `lastNumeric` to true.  If you do that, make sure to add a comment as to why it starts as true.  Another would be to add a variable to your condition.

```
if ((firstTime || lastNumeric) && !stateError)
```

You would set `firstTime = true;` in your declarations then make sure to set it false after a numeric key is pressed.

Comment: yes.it work for a while then i try to select on operation again. it still not show 12-16 23:52:02.260 18193-18193/emseyha.example.com.calculaterproject W/TextView: TextView does not support text selection. Action mode cancelled.

Comment: Did this answer fix your initial problem?

Comment: yes. it's ok  first click then second click the same to before

Comment: Glad I could help.  I was not sure since you didn't up vote or accept the answer.  I only looked at the code briefly, enough to answer the original question.  It looks like you've made a lot of changes.